# Phone number formatting in edittext in android

Tags: android

How to set phone number in the format (xxx)xxx-xxxxx while entering the phone number in the edittext in android?

I want (,),- characters are added at specific positions automatically.

**I wrote code but it works for only in andorid 2.2 version,not working in above versions.**
I searched lot more questions in stackoverflow.I couldn't get it.

please check my code:

```
phone.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher () {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable chars) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, int lengthBefore,
                    int lengthAfter) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                count = start;

                /*if (phone.getText().length() <= 0) {
                    phone.append("(");
                    phone.setSelection(1);
                }else if (count == 3) {
                    phone.append(")");
                }else if (count == 7) {
                    phone.append("-");
                }

            */

            }
        });



phone.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener (){

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(arg1 == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
                        if(count > 0){
                            count = count - 1;
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(phone.getText().length() <= 0){
                            phone.append("(");
                        }else{
                            if(count  == 3){
                                phone.append(")");
                            }else if(count == 7){
                                phone.append("-");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            });


        }
```

**Logcat showing as:**

```
01-03 15:07:23.529: W/InputManagerService(153): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40900f88
01-03 15:07:23.529: D/StatusBarPolicy(221): mFullChargeListener
01-03 15:07:25.749: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): startOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 1488
01-03 15:07:25.749: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
01-03 15:07:25.749: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): getDeviceForStrategy() from cache strategy 0, device 2
01-03 15:07:25.749: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): getNewDevice() selected device 2
01-03 15:07:25.749: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 2 delayMs 0
01-03 15:07:25.749: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setOutputDevice() setting same device 2 or null device for output 1
01-03 15:07:25.749: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): releaseOutput() 1
01-03 15:07:25.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(84): open driver
01-03 15:07:25.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(84): get config
01-03 15:07:25.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(84): set config
01-03 15:07:25.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(84): buffer_size: 4800
01-03 15:07:25.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(84): buffer_count: 2
01-03 15:07:25.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(84): channel_count: 2
01-03 15:07:25.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(84): sample_rate: 44100
01-03 15:07:25.939: W/AudioFlinger(84): write blocked for 164 msecs, 61 delayed writes, thread 0xcdd0
01-03 15:07:26.009: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): stopOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 1488
01-03 15:07:26.009: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
01-03 15:07:26.009: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): getNewDevice() selected device 0
01-03 15:07:26.009: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 0 delayMs 0
01-03 15:07:26.009: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0 or null device for output 1
01-03 15:07:26.699: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): startOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 1489
01-03 15:07:26.699: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
01-03 15:07:26.699: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): getDeviceForStrategy() from cache strategy 0, device 2
01-03 15:07:26.699: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): getNewDevice() selected device 2
01-03 15:07:26.699: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 2 delayMs 0
01-03 15:07:26.699: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setOutputDevice() setting same device 2 or null device for output 1
01-03 15:07:26.699: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): releaseOutput() 1
01-03 15:07:26.859: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): stopOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 1489
01-03 15:07:26.859: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
01-03 15:07:26.859: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): getNewDevice() selected device 0
01-03 15:07:26.859: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 0 delayMs 0
01-03 15:07:26.859: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0 or null device for output 1
01-03 15:07:27.499: I/StatusBarPolicy(221): BAT. status:5 health:2
```

Comment: Try this in your xml.  <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

Comment: Is this you were waiting??

Comment: <EditText
                android:id="@+id/businessPhone_profile"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:inputType="phone"
                 android:ems="10" 
                android:text="(" />

Comment: onkeylistener is not working properly

Comment: ok,i got it.  Its not working on samsung metroPCS. remaining all devices working

Comment: ok.I have added it in my answer.if you find something useful,then you can accept this

Answer (score 2):

Try using this library if that helps:

http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

or try this out:

```
    String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(unformattedNumber);
```

This will automatically format the number according to the rules for the country the number is from.

You can also format Editable text in-place using:

```
    PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(Editable text, int defaultFormattingType);
```

Please have a look at PhoneNumberUtils for more options.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a text changed listener that will format the phone number. There is a built in one in the [android.telephony package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html).

Its easy enough to use:

```
    phoneNumberEditText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in your xml.**

```
  <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:ems="10"
   android:inputType="phone" >
    <requestFocus />
 </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the android API can do this already
check out [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html)
specifically for US / American formatting the [FormatNanpNumber(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#formatNanpNumber%28android.text.Editable%29) method.